# How can I preserve canvas content in Elm between updates

Tags: elm

I have a question about Elm canvas. Is there a way to prevent the canvas to be erased/reinserted in the DOM on each frame?

I am trying to dynamically generate an image by changing a particle system (`Model`) and then drawing it. The pseudocode looks like bellow.

My only "solution" is not to change the particles and instead to keep adding but I am not happy with the approach.

```
type alias Particle = { ... }

type alias Model = List Particle 

update msg model =
  List.map updateParticle model

view model = 
  collage 900 900
    ((rect 900 900 |> filled bg) :: (List.map drawParticle model))


-- later edit
drawParticle p =
  segment p.start p.end
  |> traced defaultLine
```

[EDIT]
In order to make it clear what the DOM contains, I added `drawParticle` function to the code above.

Comment: Can you observe the Canvas being removed/re-inserted? I'd expect virtualdom to keep the canvas and all particles that didn't change, only removing/re-rendering elements that actually did move.

Comment: No, I didn't observe it (I can take a look, though). It was my guess but it doesn't matter. I want it to keep the drawing up to that point and just add.

Comment: Nope. It is not removed from DOM.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what it is Elm is doing that you don't want?

Comment: I got an answer on Slack. The view is a function of Model. So the history should be part of the model.

Comment: @Adrian could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've been asked in the comments to answer my own question. Although this is not the answer to my question but an workaround, and a not very efficient one.

```
type alias Particle = { ... }

type alias Model = { particles : List Particle, lines : List Form } 

update msg model =
  let 
    newParts = List.map updateParticle model.particles
    newLines = List.map particleToLine newParts
  in 
    Model newParts (model.lines ++ newLines)


view model = 
  collage 900 900
    ((rect 900 900 |> filled bg) :: model.lines)
```

What changed? First, `Model` now keep a lines list to be drawn.
`update` function produce a new set of lines every step and append it to the ones already generated.
`view` function is not rendering the particles anymore but just add the lines to the collage.

Performance wise, this is a terrible "solution" as the number of lines in the model continually increase with every `AnimationFrame`.

A better approach would be to save the image data of the canvas after every render and use it a background for next render. But I have no idea how to do this.

Hope this helps.